# symfony different form on update

Tags: php, symfony

How to handle different form fields on different actions? E.g. I want to have these fields on insert:

```
$builder
      ->add('text', 'textarea')
      ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Create!'))
;
```

And these on update:

```
$builder
    ->add('text', 'textarea')
    ->add('done', 'checkbox')
    ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Update!'))
;
```

Should I create 2 different forms(if so what would be the names of files? Currently I have only TaskType.php.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Dynamic forms based on the data. [See that doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html).

An alternative to create another form type is manually validate the checkbox using [constraints](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints.html).